# Something wrong with app.config (SQL Server Express)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, connection-string

In my app.config:

```
<add name ="connSpionshopString" connectionString="Data
Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;;AttachDbFileName=|DataDictionary|Spionshop.mdf;
Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

And in my form.cs:

```
SqlConnection conn2 = new SqlConnection();
        conn2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager
                                 .ConnectionStrings["connSpionshopString"]
                                 .ConnectionString;
```

This always gets an error: "Invalid v alue for key 'attachdbfilename'."

I don't know what's wrong with this.. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to fix it by modifying it just a tad:

```
<add name ="connSpionshopString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|Spionshop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

You had `DataDictionary` instead of `DataDirectory`

Answer (score 1):

The invalid value for key 'attachdbfilename' error can be thrown if the database server/host name is considered incorrect by the SqlConnection class. When using SQL Server Express you may only use an instance of the local host (., (local), or NETBIOS or DNS name of local machine).

that means either use like this

```
<add name ="connSpionshopString" connectionString="Data 
Source=.;AttachDbFileName=|DataDictionary|Spionshop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User 
Instance=True"/>
```

or

```
<add name ="connSpionshopString" connectionString="Data 
Source=machinename;AttachDbFileName=|DataDictionary|Spionshop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User 
Instance=True"/>
```

or

```
<add name ="connSpionshopString" connectionString="Data 
Source=(local);AttachDbFileName=|DataDictionary|Spionshop.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User 
Instance=True"/>
```

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I believe the issue is a type with DataDictionary instead of DataDirectory. Yeah? +1 for a complete answer surrounding other issues though!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a typo:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; **HERE!! ;** 
                  AttachDbFileName=|DataDictionary|Spionshop.mdf;
                  Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

You put 2 semicolons instead of one.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. But it doesn't solve the problem :(

But thanks!

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I believe the issue is a type with `DataDictionary` instead of `DataDirectory`. Yeah?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose expecting the server name of the sql database to be a local address and not /sqlexpress in DataSource variable